# Bounding the ratio of the $\ell_1$-norms of two real-valued $n$-vectors as a linear combination of their $n$ element-wise ratios

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, inequalities, sequences-and-series, combinatorial-optimization

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots b_n$ be two sequences of $n\gg 1$ real numbers such that, for all $1\le i\le n$, we have $0<a_i \le b_i\le 1$. Let the ratio $R$ defined as follows:

$$R:=\frac{\sum_{1\le i\le n} a_i}{\sum_{1\le i\le n} b_i }~.$$

---

**Question:** How can we set values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ *as functions of the ratios $r_i:=\frac{a_i}{b_i}$* in such a way that $R':=\sum_{1\le i\le n} (x_i\cdot r_i)$ is a *tight* lower bound for $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $i$, let
$x_i:=r_*/(nr_i)$, where $r_*:=\min_j r_j$, so that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are functions of the $r_i$'s. Then
$$R'=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i r_i=r_*\le R,\tag{1}$$
so that $R'$ is a lower bound on $R$. This bound is tight, since $R'=r_*=R$ if the $r_i$'s are the same for all $i$.

The inequality in (1) holds because
$$R=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n r_ib_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}
\ge\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n r_* b_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}=r_*.$$

Comment: Thank you very much @Iosif Pinelis !